# Python - CSS not present in Flask route

Tags: python, css, flask

I have a Flask app where when it goes to another route, the CSS styles that are present in the index are not present in the other route.

My index route shows the CSS styles just fine, however when it redirects to /signature, the CSS styles are not there. Here is the code below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/signature/<email> - <pronouns>')
def signature(email, pronouns):
    signature = f"<b>Matt JARRETT</b> | {pronouns} | Deskside Technician II | LV Headoffice\n | 123 Street New York, NY 10022 | 917.999.9999 | {email}"
    return render_template('signature.html', signature=signature)



@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form['email']
        pronouns = request.form['pronouns']
    
        return redirect(url_for('signature', email=email, pronouns=pronouns))

    else:
        email = request.args.get('email')
        pronouns = request.args.get('pronouns')

        return render_template('index.html')



app.run(debug=True)
```

However I noticed on the console the output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/mtthwjarrett0%40gmail.com%20-%20He-Him HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/ststic/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/select2/select2.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/select2/select2.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2022 20:59:57] "GET /signature/static/vendor/datepicker/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
...
```

So I attempted to make a signature folder with the same CSS file, but the CSS styles still doesn't load. How would I get the file to load on the other route

[image: index]
[image: /signature]

Here is the head of the HTML where the CSS is referenced:

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Colorlib Templates">
    <meta name="author" content="Colorlib">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Colorlib Templates">

    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>LV Email Signature Generator</title>

    <!-- Icons font CSS-->
    <link href="static/vendor/mdi-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="ststic/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Vendor CSS-->
    <link href="static/vendor/select2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link href="static/vendor/datepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
```

Comment: Have you set up your static route?  You have to tell it which routes to handle.

Comment: You have a typo in ` <link href="ststic/vendor/font-awesome-4.7/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <!-- Font special for pages-->` it should be `static/vendor`.
This might be at least part of the problem.

And if the files are in signature/static folder then you should do href="signature/static..."

You should take a look at how to handle static files in flask because you are probably not doing it as you should (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#static-files)